# Control function bootstrapped standard errors

Tags: bootstrap, standard-error, stata, instrumental-variables, two-step-estimation

Using a control function approach allows to incorporate non-linear first-stage specifications. A problem when doing this approach is that the naive standard errors are too small since they do not account for the fact that we use generated regressors. One solution, as for example suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126313/standard-errors-of-a-two-stage-least-squares-regression-stata) is to bootstrap the standard errors instead.

I tried to compare the results of the bootstrapped version with the standard 2sls estimates for the linear case where both versions are readily implementable. The coefficients are, expectedly, in line across the specifications. The standard errors are, however, wildly off. The uncorrected standard errors of the two-step approach are just slightly too small, and when we bootstrap they increase way too much. In fact, the non-adjusted standard errors are much better than the bootstrapped ones.

Below is the Stata example using Wooldridge's fish dataset.

```
// Install programs
*ssc install bcuse
*ssc install ivreg2

bcuse fish, clear

rename lavgprc p
rename ltotqty q
qui su speed2, det
gen stormy = (speed2 > r(p50))

capture program drop cf
program define cf
    capture drop resid
    qui reg p stormy i.mon i.tues i.wed i.thurs
    predict resid, resid
    reg q p i.mon i.tues i.wed i.thurs resid
end


// 1. 2SLS
ivregress 2sls q i.mon i.tues i.wed i.thurs (p = stormy) 

// 2. Control Function
cf

// 3. Bootstrapped Control Function
bootstrap, reps(1000) seed(12345) : cf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some simple R code demonstrating that bootstrapping the control function estimator has a correct coverage rate.  It uses a simple x-y bootstrap with 200 resamples.  Not the most efficient code in the world, takes less that two minutes for 200 repetitions of the process (and was quick to write up).  I don't use the example you give above because one requires knowledge of the truth to assess coverage rates, and so a simulation is required.

```
set.seed(1234)
library(pbapply)

# Function for control function estimation, potentially re-sampled
one_run <- function(y,x,z,boot=F){
  
  d <- data.frame(y=y,x=x,z=z)
  
  if(boot == T){
    ind <- 1:nrow(d)
    ind <- sample(ind,nrow(d),replace = T)
    d <- d[ind,]
  }
  
  fs <- lm(x ~ z, data = d)
  ss <- lm(y ~ x + fs$residuals, data = d)
  ss$coefficients
  
}

# Number of simulations to assess coverage rate
n_sims <- 200

# Simulate process repeatedly with bootstraped control function
pblapply(1:n_sims, function(i){
  
  # Data-generation process
  nobs <- 100
  c <- rnorm(nobs)
  z <- rnorm(nobs)
  x <- c + z + rnorm(nobs)
  y <- c + x + rnorm(nobs)
  
  
  boots <- lapply(1:200, function(q)one_run(y,x,z, boot = T))
  boots <- do.call("rbind",boots)
  boots <- as.data.frame(boots)
  quantile(boots$x,c(0.025,0.975))
  
}) -> out
  

# Collect and combine results  
all <- do.call("rbind", out)
all <- as.data.frame(all)
names(all) <- c("lower","upper")

all$covered <- ifelse(all$lower <= 1 & all$upper >= 1, 1, 0)
summary(all)
```

Running the above shows that the truth falls within the bootstrapped confidence intervals at the desired 0.95 rate, which means that the confidence intervals are of the desired size.

Worth note is that one may occasionally get bootstrap intervals which are particularly wide or narrow, just like you might get analytic standard errors which are particularly wide or narrow relative to the what you would expect under repeated sampling because of the peculiarities of a given sample.

For example, the smallest interval observed in the above simulation was of width 0.29 [0.89, 1.19] while the largest was of width 1.36 [-0.26, 1.09]; this demonstrates the conceptual issue with the approach you took above.  While in expectation the bootstrap and analytical standard errors to be approximately equal since they target the same theoretical quantity, the comparison of any individual bootstrap with any individual analytic standard error may be wildly different.